# ¿Cómo eliminar el fondo blanco de una imagen en Python con opencv?

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente código y me funciona muy bien, lo que hace es sencillo.

En escencia es verificar que haya una cámara conectada, si resulta `true` simplemente captura una foto y la guarda como ***foto.png***, si es `false` muestra un mensaje de error, hasta ahí todo bien, ahora lo que necesito hacer con la foto que acabo de tomar es quitarle el fondo.

Cabe resaltar que el fondo siempre va ser blanco, utilizo linux, pero creo que es irrelevante.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
"""
    En este caso, 0 quiere decir que queremos acceder
    a la cámara 0. Si hay más cámaras, puedes ir probando
    con 1, 2, 3...
"""
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
read, frame = cap.read()

if read == True:
    cv2.imwrite("foto.png", frame)
    print("Foto tomada correctamente")
else:
    print("Error al acceder a la cámara")
    #Finalmente liberamos o soltamos la cámara
cap.release()
```

Comment: ¿Eliminar o más bien reemplazar el blanco de fondo por otro color o transparencia?

Comment: ¿Podrías publicar algún ejemplo de una imagen de prueba?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He mejorado mi código de manera considerable

- además de eliminar el fondo y pintarlo completamente blanco
- le he metido un `for` para que tome la cantidad de fotos que desee, en este caso se cambiaría en el ***range*** `for acum in range(40):`
- e inmediatamente le organice el fondo completamente blanco o del color que yo quiera en la parte de ***Parameter,*** guardará las fotos en una carpeta que definí ***img.***

  MASK_COLOR = (1.0,1.0,1.0) # In BGR format

Anexo el código por si alguien más lo necesite en algún proyecto.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#== Parameters ======================================================================= 
BLUR = 21 
CANNY_THRESH_1 = 10 
CANNY_THRESH_2 = 200 
MASK_DILATE_ITER = 10 
MASK_ERODE_ITER = 10 
MASK_COLOR = (1.0,1.0,1.0) # In BGR format 

#== Processing ======================================================================= 

#== Camera 1, 2 or n ================================================================= 
for acum in range(40):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    read, frame = cap.read()

    if read == True:
    
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
        frame[np.all(frame == [255, 255, 255, 255], axis=2)] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
        cv2.imwrite("img/foto"+str(acum)+".png", frame)
        print("Photo taken correctly")
        #== Processing ======================================================================= 

        #-- Read image ----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        img = cv2.imread("img/foto"+str(acum)+".png") 
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 

        #-- Edge detection ------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        edges = cv2.Canny(gray, CANNY_THRESH_1, CANNY_THRESH_2) 
        edges = cv2.dilate(edges, None) 
        edges = cv2.erode(edges, None) 

        #-- Find contours in edges, sort by area --------------------------------------------- 
        contour_info = [] 
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) 
        for c in contours: 
            contour_info.append((
            c, 
            cv2.isContourConvex(c), 
            cv2.contourArea(c), 
            )) 
        contour_info = sorted(contour_info, key=lambda c: c[2], reverse=True) 
        max_contour = contour_info[0] 

        #-- Create empty mask, draw filled polygon on it corresponding to largest contour ---- 
        # Mask is black, polygon is white 
        mask = np.zeros(edges.shape) 
        cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, max_contour[0], (255)) 

        #-- Smooth mask, then blur it -------------------------------------------------------- 
        mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=MASK_DILATE_ITER) 
        mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=MASK_ERODE_ITER) 
        mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (BLUR, BLUR), 0) 
        mask_stack = np.dstack([mask]*3) # Create 3-channel alpha mask 

        #-- Blend masked img into MASK_COLOR background -------------------------------------- 
        mask_stack = mask_stack.astype('float32')/255.0   # Use float matrices, 
        img   = img.astype('float32')/255.0     # for easy blending 

        masked = (mask_stack * img) + ((1-mask_stack) * MASK_COLOR) # Blend 
        masked = (masked * 255).astype('uint8')      # Convert back to 8-bit 

        cv2.imwrite("img/foto"+str(acum)+".png", masked)   # Save
    else:
        print("Error accessing camera")
        #We finally released the camera
    cap.release()
```

[Publicación en la cual me basé](https://www.oipapio.com/question-1750994)

Comment: +1. Pero queda más elegante citar la fuente de dónde has basado tu respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29314286/6836377. Si no es así disculpa mi comentario.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Si tienes razón, aunque no lo saqué de ese post, es muy similiar, voy a buscarlo de nuevo y lo incluiré, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Os traigo la respuesta desde http://benjamintan.io/blog/2018/05/24/making-transparent-backgrounds-with-numpy-and-opencv-in-python/

A tu código debes agregar:

```
frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
```

para añadir el canal *alpha* a la imagen (presta atención al orden de los colores: BGR y no RGB), y

```
frame[np.all(frame == [255, 255, 255, 255], axis=2)] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

para buscar los píxeles que son **blancos**, es decir (255, 255, 255) en BGR. En la misma línea reemplazas los colores.

Para cambiar píxeles que no son completamente blancos, puedes cambiar la línea anterior por

```
frame[np.all(np.isclose(frame, [255, 255, 255, 255], atol=200), axis=2)] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

donde el valor de atol (`atol=200`) indica qué tan cercano es el valor, siendo 200 un valor bastante elevado.

Os dejo el código completo:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
"""
    En este caso, 0 quiere decir que queremos acceder
    a la cámara 0. Si hay más cámaras, puedes ir probando
    con 1, 2, 3...
"""
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
read, frame = cap.read()

if read == True:
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
    #frame[np.all(frame == [255, 255, 255, 255], axis=2)] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    frame[np.all(np.isclose(frame, [255, 255, 255, 255], atol=200), axis=2)] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    cv2.imwrite("foto.png", frame)
    print("Foto tomada correctamente")
else:
    print("Error al acceder a la cámara")
    #Finalmente liberamos o soltamos la cámara
cap.release()
```

Comment: Buenos días amigo, estuve revisando el link, pero creo que no es el enfoque para lo que lo necesito, e igualmente al ejecutar le python actúa completamente igual al que tenía, igualmente muchas gracias por tu colaboración.

Comment: ¿Estáis seguro que el problema no es que el color a reemplazar no es **exactamente** blanco? He agregado código para reemplazar el color según su cercanía al color (que sería mejor definir como parámetros).